# Cart item total clears on home page

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a strange problem and hope someone may have an answer, in my header I have a box saying items in cart.

When I add an item to my cart all works fine even when I'm on the home page, I then go to another page all is fine still, when I go back to home page the total clears and says 0 but when I go to basket the products I added are still there, go back to another page and works fine.

Problem seems only to be on home page.

After some research it looks like it might have something to do with an extension I am using Lesti FPC (Full Page Cache) and lazy blocks (i may be wrong) only thing is I'm not sure on what block name controls this or if it is even this causing the problem.

Another possibility mentioned was cookie lifetime although this is set to 86400 which I believe is plenty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I would try disabling Full Page Cache and clearing all cache, then see if you can re-create the problem. That'll help narrow it down a little.

Comment: Good idea don't know why I didn't think of that  thanks for the advice

Comment: Yes that works fine definitely to do with extension i know you can add blocks to exclude from the cache process unsure what block to add don't suppose you know at all thanks again

Comment: I'm not certain. It might be Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Minicart or possibly Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar. Once you find it, you should be able to implement some sort of "hole punching" to keep it from being cached, but I'm not familiar with that exact extension.

Comment: Fixed it I had to add block-cart-header under system/permissions/blocks all works fine thanks for you help versalle88 very decent of you to take the time to help

Comment: Actually maybe I have caused another issue when on different browsers it comes up with same total in all browsers if that makes sense I'm sure its not supposed to

Comment: If you're logged in to Magento as the same user in those other browsers, the totals should be the same. If you're logged in as a different user or not logged in, they probably shouldn't be (unless you've added the same number to your cart as the other user / guest).